# Could not open no_buildscript class cache for script

Tags: gradle

When I executed a `gradle` command (Cygwin environment):

```
gradle cleanidea eclipse
```

It went wrong with this error log:

```
Could not open no_buildscript class cache for script 'jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/gradle-2.5/lib/gradle-core-2.5.jar!/org/gradle/initialization/buildsrc/defaultBuildSourceScript.txt' (C:\Users\mingle\.gradle\caches\2.5\scripts\defaultBuildSourceScript_ehlybs1v0v6kbup5qmtxh65v\DefaultScript\no_buildscript).

Signature Parse error: Expected Field Type Signature
        Remaining input: +Ljava/util/Spliterator$OfInt;
```

I tried to run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.
This is the exception thrown:

```
org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open no_buildscript class cache for script 'jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/gradle-2.5/lib/gradle-core-2.5.jar!/org/gradle/initialization/buildsrc/defaultBuildSourceScript.txt' (C:\Users\mingle\.gradle\caches\2.5\scripts\defaultBuildSourceScript_ehlybs1v0v6kbup5qmtxh65v\DefaultScript\no_buildscript).
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:48)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:28)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:80)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:50)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.doOpen(DefaultCacheRepository.java:138)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$AbstractCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:121)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:63)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.compile(ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.java:53)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(CachingScriptClassCompiler.java:41)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:50)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyScript(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:102)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$000(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$1.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
        at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSrcBuildListenerFactory$Listener.projectsLoaded(BuildSrcBuildListenerFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.projectsLoaded(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.projectsLoaded(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:135)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:189)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runRootBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:184)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSrcUpdateFactory.create(BuildSrcUpdateFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSrcUpdateFactory.create(BuildSrcUpdateFactory.java:31)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:102)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:183)
        at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder.createBuildSourceClasspath(BuildSourceBuilder.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder.buildAndCreateClassLoader(BuildSourceBuilder.java:51)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(SettingsHandler.java:87)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:189)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runRootBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:184)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: Expected Field Type Signature
        Remaining input: +Ljava/util/Spliterator$OfInt;
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:125)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:82)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CacheInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:113)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CacheInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:92)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:130)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:117)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:94)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.run(DefaultCacheAccess.java:104)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:173)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:163)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:102)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:46)
        ... 89 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.66 secs
```

Comment: When posting questions, it is generally better to post as little as is necessary to help others understand the error. Including the entire debug log is a bit much.

Comment: I will pay attention to this problem next time.I used the Windows10 OS and I found that it is the authority problem.When I run cygwin as administrator,it works well.

Answer (score 0):

go to location

```
"C:\Users\{user}\.gradle\caches\{gradleversion}\scripts\build_6h6bbv9gdr9rlbqilttig2ii08\ProjectScript\buildscript"
```

and delete cache.properties.lock file